# Prepositional phrasal verbs in passive voice

Tags: phrasal-verbs, passive-voice, transitive-verbs

I wanted to clarify the question of prepositional phrasal verbs for myself.
I have faced a tricky sentence, and I would like to discover if I can change the location of the preposition 'at'. If not, I would like to understand why. Here is the sentence:

He is handsome enough to be looked at by any passenger.

Can the sentence be changed to:

He is handsome enough to be looked by any passenger at.

The verb 'look at' is a prepositional phrasal verb. It is intransitive in the active voice: 'I look at you'. Can we turn this into the passive voice as: 'You are looked by me at'? Does the preposition 'at' turn into an adverb in that case?

Thank you.

Comment: No. _Look at_ is not a phrasal verb. Transitive phrasal verbs like _look up_ can  undergo Particle Shift, like _Look up the word ~ Look the word up_. But  the _at_ in _look at_ is just a preposition that makes intransitive _look_ transitive. It's not a particle, and doesn't shift. Similar remarks apply to _listen to_ and many other intranstive verbs that can be made transitive with some preposition (which one varies).

Comment: Thank you. This I understand, however, I wanted to clarify if the sentence 'He is handsome enough to be looked by any passenger at' is allowed with that location of the preposition, and if it is, why?